# TypeError: el.visible is not a function - checking if element is visible after scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, typeerror

I have scroll animation that I only want to fire once. After the element is already visible I want to add another class ('already-visible') to stop the animation. I am getting a Uncaught TypeError that **el.visible is not a function**. Is this a syntax error?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*SCROLL ICONS-----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------*/
var $animation_elements = $('.show-on-scroll');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
    var window_height = $window.height();
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

    $.each($animation_elements, function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
        var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

        //check to see if this current container is within viewport
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
            (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
            $element.addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            $element.removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');

/*END SCROLL ICONS-----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------*/



var win = $(window);
var allMods = $('.show-on-scroll');

// Already visible modules
allMods.each(function(check_if_in_view) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("already-visible");
    }
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(check_if_in_view) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("already-visible");
        }
    });

});
```

});

Comment: maybe: el.is(':visible')?

Comment: Thank you - that took care of it-